# IE conditional statement for IE8 and IE 11

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have a requirement on IE conditional statement with IE 8 and IE 11, if IE is IE 11 then load script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ie8/test.js"></script>
else
load  below script for ie11 and other browser
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ie11/test.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to play with IE versions (`lt` means less than):

```
<head>
   ....

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="yourscriptIE8.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    ....
</head>
```

You can have multiple such statements with scripts for different versions.

Comment: thanks for quick answer But this condition will not work for IE11

Comment: i am looking way to get IE version value in all the IE version (IE 8 to 12)

Comment: you mean, you need to check if browser is IE or what ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ie8/test.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if (IE 11)|(!IE)]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ie11/test.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

The first if will load the script only in IE8, the second if will load the script only if IE11 or other browsers.
You can find more information about HTML conditional comments [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx)